# mysql - how to cast BINARY(4) as an integer

Tags: mysql, hash, casting, binary

I want to take the first four bytes of a BINARY string and interpret it as numeric.

(Background: I have a SHA1 hash that has been UNHEX'ed into a BINARY(20) column, and I want to create a PARTITION BY HASH expression that takes the first four bytes of the SHA1 value and casts or converts it to a numeric value, as the PARTITION BY HASH expression is expected to.)

It really needn't be four bytes; just a short run of a few bytes that can be manipulated into being seen as an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but,

Try this:

```
SELECT CONV(LEFT(HEX(<column_with_bin_str>),8), 16, 10) FROM Table;
```

This would convert the binary string to hex, take the first 8 hex characters from the converted string and convert that to decimal.

We take the first 8 hex characters as two hex characters are needed to represent one byte.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the follwing two functions::

[SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

> returns a substring len characters long from string str, starting at
>   position pos.

---

[CONV(N,from_base,to_base)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) -

> Converts numbers between different number bases. Returns a string
>   representation of the number N, converted from base from_base to base
>   to_base.

---

**EDIT**

If you need to get the 4 first digits of `10011001` which is `1001 = 9` use:

```
SELECT CONV(SUBSTR(10011001, 1, 4), 2, 10)
```

if you have *leading zeros* you can use the LPAD function, for example the first 4 digits of  the binary value `01001100` which is `0100 = 4`, you can do:

```
SELECT CONV(
  SUBSTR(
    LPAD(
      CAST(01001100 as char), (LENGTH(CAST(01001100 as char)) + 1), '0'), 
    1, 4), 2, 10)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8460)

Comment: Close.  I think CONV wants N to be an ASCII representation.  As I mentioned above, I'm working with a true binary "string."  Here's what I tried: 
select conv(substr(unhex(sha1('a')),1,1),2,10);
I'll keep fiddling.